# How to open a web browser for a Run/Debug Configuration in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, web, phpstorm

My specs:

- OS: Arch Linux
- WM: KDE Plasma
- PHP: 7.2.1 (with XDebug)
- PhpStorm: 2017.3.3

I have these settings in PhpStorm:
[image: img01]

[image: img02]

[image: img03]

When starting PhpStorm, the port 7999 is always listening. I have to start manually the web server specified in "Run/Debug Configuration" then port 8000 is listening too.

My problem is when trying to run any script from editor by using browser popup, i.e., this file:

```
~/Projects/PHP/LearningPHP/ch01/ex0102-form.html
```

By using browser popup, web browser opens this URL:

```
http://localhost:7999/LearningPHP/ex0102-form.html?_ijt=cfvfi8l80ks1r42h10and6krpr
```

and I can get one error if this file is calling another file located in subdirectory "ch01".

I'd wish this browser popup opens the resource according to "Run/Debug Configuration", meanwhile I have to input manually in web browser this URL:

```
http://localhost:8000/ch01/ex0102-form.html
```

So I have three questions:

1. How can PhpStorm be configured according to my wish?
2. <strike>When and What is port 7999 used for?</strike> If service using port 7999 is a PhpStorm built-in (web) server, why are URLs made by this server different to that one made by webservers configured in "Run/Debug Configuration"? Can it be fixed?
3. <strike>What's the difference between services using ports 7999 and 8000?</strike>

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 2. It's PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server; also used for communicating with browser (e.g. JavaScript debug) etc. If serving web pages this way -- the URL will be `localhost:7999/PROJECT_NAME/path/to/desired/file`) 3. 8000 (as per your screenshot) is PHP's built-in web server that needs to be launched manually - see http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: Just install WAMP/XAMPP or alike and use proper Apache -- the best solution for you. Or try Vagrant/Docker (server run in some VM/container).

Comment: Thanks LazyOne, your first comment is not an answer for my first question, 'cause I'm trying to set up PhpStorm since I'm learning PHP, I'll eventually  use some solution like XAMP, Vagrant, etc. but that is not the problem for the moment. I gonna reformulate my third question. Thanks again.

Comment: *"why are URLs made by this server different to that one made by webservers configured in "Run/Debug Configuration"? Can it be fixed?"* because it's simple web server and meant for basic things and your case may not be suitable. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+Built-in+Webserver+in+PhpStorm and other manuals/howtos: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials

Comment: *"Thanks LazyOne, your first comment is not an answer for my first question"* I have not even tried to answer 1st question -- only 2nd and 3rd.